# How to know fields name of array by JSON code

Tags: json

I have a code  :

```
  var ListeSortie = 
  [
    {
      "Champ1": "Texte 1",
      "Champ2": "Texte 2",
      "Champ3": "Texte 3"
    },
    {
      "Champ4": "Texte 4",
      "Champ5": "Texte 5",
      "Champ6": "Texte 6"
    }
  ] 

  console.log('_______Liste 1_____________')
  console.log(ListeSortie[0])
  console.log('_______Liste 2_____________')
  console.log(ListeSortie[1])
```

the Output :

```
_______Liste 1_____________
{Champ1: "Texte 1", Champ2: "Texte 2", Champ3: "Texte 3"}
_______Liste 2_____________
{Champ4: "Texte 4", Champ5: "Texte 5", Champ6: "Texte 6"}
```

My question : How can i do to have juste the value Name of my objet like this:

```
Champ1
Champ2
Champ3
Champ4
Champ5
Champ6
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: look at [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your array and use `Object.keys` method to get the keys.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:
First we loop through the `ListeSortie` to get the list of object in the `ListeSortie`.
Then we use the method Object.keys to get the key from the object inside `ListeSortie`.
Lastly, we for each every keys array and console.log the value.

```js
ListeSortie.forEach(x => Object.keys(x).forEach(y => console.log(y)))
```

Comment: Good !   Many Thinks